# Which of the following series will converge and which one will diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me out that which of the following series will converge and which one will diverge, with some explanation?

A) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)$

B) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What does $\cos(\pi/n)$ approach as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Euler said that if $x$ is an infinitely small positive number than $\sin x=x$.  Today we way $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$.  At any rate we know that if $x$ is a sufficiently small positive number then
$$
\frac x 2 <\sin x < x,
$$
so
$$
\frac\pi2\sum_n \frac 1 n =\sum_n \frac\pi{2n}\le\sum_n \sin\frac \pi n \le \sum_n \frac \pi n = \pi\sum_n \frac 1 n.
$$
Can you do the rest?

As for the other series, the terms don't approach $0$.